# If $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is a subset of $\{a_n\}$, $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k }= \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\ $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence and L a real number such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$ Prove that if $\{a_{n_k}\}$ is any subsequence of $\{a_n\}$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} = L $

I have found the following proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary,
$|a_n -L| < \epsilon$
and
$|a_{n_k} -L| < \epsilon$
$N>0, n \geq N$

At some $k>N$ $a_n=a_{n_k}$

Therefore, the limit of $a_{n_k}$ is equal to the limit of $a_n$

Now, is there an alternative proof for this that is simpler or more "complete" than the one I have shown?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "*At some $k > n$, $a_n = a_{n_k}$"*?  Why should this be the case?

Comment: You're better off saying something like "there exists a $K$ such that when $k > K$, $n_k > N$".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that statment just says that there exists values of k in which $a_{n_k} = a_n$

Comment: Well, that is not the case for every $n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom give me an example...

Comment: for example, take $n_k = 2k$ and $n = 5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that $a_{n_k} \to L$, which means, that given $\epsilon >0$ there exist $k_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $k \geq k_0$ implies $|a_{n_k}-L|< \epsilon$ You know that for that given $\epsilon$ there exist $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that  $n \geq N$ implies $|a_{n}-L|< \epsilon$ So in order to be sure that $|a_{n_k}-L|< \epsilon$ you have to take your $k_0$ such that $k \geq k_0$ implies $n_k \geq N$